# The argument type 'AsyncSnapshot<Object?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: sql, json, flutter, sqlite, flutter-futurebuilder

I had a factory method for converting json into an object which accepted **Map<String, dynamic> json** as argument from sqlite database like below

```
 factory Lecturer.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)=>Lecturer(
    name:json['name'],
    email: json['email'],
  );
```

the data is returned in a future builder and access like this

```
          FutureBuilder(
              future: DB.getLecturer(),
              builder: (_,lect){
                if(!lect.hasData){
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
               Lecturer l=Lecturer.fromJson(lect.data[0]);
              }),
```

but after upgrading my flutter to a newer version I realized the return type for SQL queries is no longer **Map<String, dynamic>** but rather **Map<String, Object?>** , I now get the error below from a code that was working perfectly just last week. Please any help will be appreciated

```
Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'
```

Comment: What are you doing inside `DB.getLecturer()` and why not receive `Lecturer` from future?

Answer (score 0):

in you builder specify the lect type as AsyncSnapshot:

```
      builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot lect){
        if(!lect.hasData){
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }               
           Lecturer l=Lecturer.fromJson(lect.data[0]);
          }
```