# Included null safety libs and now code is not running

Tags: flutter, dart

I have used null safety libs. Now am getting this problem. Please see the screenshot.
Even after adding a null check, it's not going.

[image]

```
body: FutureBuilder(
    future: allPerson(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
      return snapshot.hasData
          ? ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                List list = snapshot.data;
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Container(
                      width: 100,
                      height: 100,
                      child: Image.network(
                          "http://192.168.1.101/image_upload_php_mysql/uploads/${list[index]['image']}"),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Center(child: Text(list[index]['name'])),
                  ),
                );
              })
          : Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
    },
  ),
```

Thanks.

Comment: share you code not image

Comment: We're not here to provide all the code ourselves. include your code not only a screenshot.

Comment: refer to my answer here for lenght is not defined error : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69142424/the-argument-type-asyncsnapshotobject-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-ty/69142526#69142526

Comment: Code added. Thanks

Comment: Please ```builder: (context, snapshot) {```` hover on the builder you will find which type of response your snapshot query is returning. if possible then try to add show the query

Answer (score 1):

You can give a type to your returned value(s) from `future` function for `snapshot` data.

```
FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
        future: allPerson(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In null safety, you can not set a nullable variable(a variable that can be set as null) to non nullable variable(a variable that doesn't accept the value null).

Here itemCount is non nullable variable, however the variable data is nullable, and may not be available to access the variable length.

```
itemCount: snapshot.data.length
```

Try altering it to the following code

```
itemCount: snapshot.data?["length"] ?? 0
```

Comment: @JituSingh have updated my answer for you, you should try it out

Answer (score 0):

snapshot.data can be null. So you should use snapshot.data?.length ?? 0

So if snapshot.data is null then it will set length as 0.

Comment: The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.

Answer (score 0):

just do this
`itemCount: snapshot.data!.length`

and the problem will gone

Comment: The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Created variable but no luck.